# VLC Player running in the background as root with 100% CPU usage

Tags: vlc, 20.04, cpu-load

After installing VLC Player on Ubuntu 20.04, I have found that sometimes the program will run in the background under the root user and consume 100% CPU. I don't know what the exact circumstances are but it seems to do with opening an invalid or unsupported file.

I unfortunately did not get a screenshot of the system monitor when this last happened but will make sure to take one the next time it does.

Does anyone have a solution to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: Upon further testing, it would appear that this does not happen due to opening an invalid file but instead, a file on external storage (an SD card in my case). VLC seems to be endlessly loading the file when opened and after closing, stays in the background. Unmounting the removable media results in a warning that a process is using it. I believe this is what happened last time. Thus far I was not able to reproduce the "running as root" and "100%" CPU part. Currently VLC is running in background at a constant 8% CPU usage and gradually bringing up my fan speed.

EDIT2: Screenshot of the "properties" of the process:

[image]

What's interesting is that the process seems to be using only a single CPU core to 100% (core 10):

[image]

EDIT3: The process must be forcefully killed. Ending the process does not work at all.

Comment: 100% CPU is probably cause by VLC trying to open invalid file but should drop after.  VLC running under root should only happen if it is open with sudo, which you should not be doing.

Comment: @crip659 Nope, not running it as root. I run it by clicking a media file from a normal user account. However, System Monitor says that the process is running with sudo privileges.

Comment: Think maybe a re install of VLC might be easiest to try unless someone else has better idea.  Check if it happens with a file that VLC knows how to use.

Comment: @crip659 I've done some testing. See the edit.